# parsing javascript function to two different button onclick

Tags: javascript, function, sip, pjsip

Hi guys I seperated the function in below to two seperate function. The functions doesn't work but I don't get any error any idea?
Main Function:

```
function sipToggleMute() {
            if (oSipSessionCall) {
                var i_ret;
                var bMute = !oSipSessionCall.bMute;
                txtCallStatus.innerHTML = bMute ? '<i>Mute the call...</i>' : '<i>Unmute the call...</i>';
                i_ret = oSipSessionCall.mute('audio'/*could be 'video'*/, bMute);
                if (i_ret != 0) {
                    txtCallStatus.innerHTML = '<i>Mute / Unmute failed</i>';
                    return;
                }
                oSipSessionCall.bMute = bMute;
                btnMute.value = bMute ? "Unmute" : "Mute";
            }
        }
```

parsed functions:

```
function sipMute() {
if (oSipSessionCall) {
    var i_ret;
    var bMute = !oSipSessionCall.bMute;
    txtCallStatus.innerHTML = '<i>Mute the call...</i>';
    i_ret = oSipSessionCall.mute('audio'/*could be 'video'*/, bMute);
    if (i_ret != 0) {
        txtCallStatus.innerHTML = '<i>Mute failed</i>';
        return;
    }
    oSipSessionCall.bMute = "Unmute";
}
```

}

```
function sipunMute() {
    if (oSipSessionCall) {
        var i_ret;
        var bMute = !oSipSessionCall.bMute;
        txtCallStatus.innerHTML =  '<i>Unmute the call...</i>';
        i_ret = oSipSessionCall.mute('audio', bMute);
        if (i_ret != 0) {
            txtCallStatus.innerHTML = '<i> Unmute failed</i>';
            return;
        }
        oSipSessionCall.bMute = "Mute";
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by parsed? When are you calling the "parsed" functions? If you do call them elsewhere, please post the code (HTML for example?)

Comment: First thanks for response. The problem is that I have one button in my code. Every time when I need to unmute of mute I press to that button and the button value changed between the mute and unmute. Now I simply want to the function in above to two different mute and unmute functions which can be accecable just but onclick.

Comment: In your "parsed functions", the value of `bMute` will *always* be `false`, because you set `osipSessionCall.bMute = "...'`, which is a non-empty string, and is therefore truthy.  That means `!osipSessionCall.bMute` is `true`.  This is fundamental Javascript. See:  http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an initial state of false (not muted) of your `oSipSessionCall.bMute` property:

```
var oSipSessionCall = {
  bMute: false
}
```

You can use a single toggle function to mute and un-mute your player (I'm assuming you are using jQuery and your button has a name property `toggle`):

```
$('[name=toggle]').on('click', function() {
  var i_ret;

  if (oSipSessionCall) {
    txtCallStatus.innerHTML = oSipSessionCall.bMute ? '<i>Mute the call...</i>' : '<i>Unmute the call...</i>';
    i_ret = oSipSessionCall.mute('audio'/*could be 'video'*/, oSipSessionCall.bMute);

    if (i_ret !== 0) {
      txtCallStatus.innerHTML = '<i>Mute failed</i>';
      return;
    }

    oSipSessionCall.bMute = !oSipSessionCall.bMute;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your functions are toggling the current state, due to:

```
var bMute = !oSipSessionCall.bMute;
```

One function should set to `true`, the other should set to `false`

```
function sipMute() {
    if (oSipSessionCall) {
        var i_ret;
        var bMute = true;
        txtCallStatus.innerHTML = '<i>Mute the call...</i>';
        i_ret = oSipSessionCall.mute('audio'/*could be 'video'*/, bMute);
        if (i_ret != 0) {
            txtCallStatus.innerHTML = '<i>Mute failed</i>';
            return;
        }
        oSipSessionCall.bMute = bMute;
        // btnMute.value = "Unmute";
}
```

.

```
function sipunMute() {
    if (oSipSessionCall) {
        var i_ret;
        var bMute = false;
        txtCallStatus.innerHTML =  '<i>Unmute the call...</i>'
        i_ret = oSipSessionCall.mute('audio', bMute);
        if (i_ret != 0) {
            txtCallStatus.innerHTML = '<i> Unmute failed</i>';
            return;
        }
        oSipSessionCall.bMute = bMute;
        //btnMute.value = "Mute";
    }
```

If you have two different buttons, say `btnMute` and `btnUnmute`, then you don't need the `btnMute.value...`.